# Pass javascript array to c# list object for user defined class

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a javascript array which is passed as a parameter in javascript `$.post` to C# List object as follows

```
arrSelectedList
```

It contains the list of vehicles as integers that are selected and the model class for it in javascript is

```
function Vehicle() {
    this.type = "Vehicle";
    this.data = {
        VehicleKey:null
    }
};
```

In the front-end there is some preparation before using `$.post` and is as follows

```
var objectToSend = GetReport(arrSelectedList, screen);
```

The `GetReport` function in javascript is as follows

```
function GetReport(client, screen) {
    var reportObject = new Vehicle();
    reportObject.data.vehicleKey = client.VehicleKey ? client.VehicleKey : null;
    return reportObject
}
```

and this

```
$.post(url, objectToSend.data)
```

In MVC, the Custom class is defined as follows

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string VehicleKey{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is the C# code

```
public string CreateReport(List<Vehicle> vehicleKey)
{
}
```

When I check for the value in the C# method parameter, I am getting empty value.
But when I pass the parameter as `arrSelectedList[0]`, I get the value as 71 and is getting submitted properly and I am able to generate the report for single value. If I pass array, I get the value as empty.

Please clarify.

**EDIT**

**I have changed the question for simplicity. Hope you can understand better.**

Comment: How does the method that you post to looks like? The one defined by `url`?

Comment: Browser Developer tools Network tab will allow you to see the actual data submitted. Can you show us the Post Data?

Comment: I am getting the data using `Route("api/getreport")` and `[HttpPost]` attribute is applied to the method `CreateReport`. There is some confusion in the definition of custom class in javascript and c#. I think both are not matching. And the data I am submitting is an array with integer values for `vehicleKey` property.

Comment: Even if I pass a single value directly in `$.post`, it is not coming to the `List<Vehicle> vehicle` parameter in MVC. How should I define the parameter as to retrieve as array.

Comment: You're not sending an array. `reportObject.data.vehicleKey = client.VehicleKey ? client.VehicleKey : null;` --> `client` here is a string, it does not have a `VehicleKey` field hence will always returns `null`... never an array.

Comment: If I pass `var objectToSend = GetReport(arrSelectedList[0], screen);         $.post(url, objectToSend.data);`, I get proper value in C# as Vehicle object. Here I would like to know on how to define array in javascript and get as a List object in MVC parameter. Something similar to List<Vehicle> in javascript. I am getting value for Vehicle.VehicleKey as 71 which is proper for my results in generating a report. The problem occurs when an array is passed in javascript.

Comment: Something like `function GetReport(client, screen) {
    var reportObject = new Vehicle[]();
    reportObject.data.vehicleKey[] = client.VehicleKey[] ? client.VehicleKey[] : null;
    return reportObject
}`. Will this work?